# Redux Watch not responding to changes in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to monitor the change in a redux store attribute by subscribing to the change using redux watch.  For one attribute it works fine.  For another, I am making an API request in the reducer (can't make async requests in the actions).
I have verified that the redux state does indeed get updated by creating a button to display the new information.
However, my component isn't actually subscribing to the change. 
Does anyone know why this is?

```
import watch from 'redux-watch';
import {store} from '../index.js';

class ListResults extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      profiles: [],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    let w = watch(store.getState, 'searchResults');
     store.subscribe(w((newVal, oldVal, objectPath) => {

          // not getting called
          console.log("Successfully got new searchResults")
    }))

  }

...
render() {
...
}
...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
       searchResults: state.searchResults,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListResults);
```

Comment: have u got any error?

Comment: No error at all.

Answer (score 0):

Redux reducers must be pure functions!

> ... making an API request in the reducer (can't make async requests in the actions).

sounds very much like a incorrect reducer implementation.

In order to make async requests with redux you should look into redux middleware, like `redux-thunk`, `redux-observables` or `redux-saga`